# Area between paraboloid cut out by cylinder

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, analytic-geometry, area, multiple-integral

> Find area between surface $z^2=x^2+y^2$ and $x^2+y^2=2x$.

So, after using polar coordinates $x=r\cos \phi,y=r\sin \phi$ i get $0\le r \le 2\cos\phi$ and $0\le \phi \le \frac{\pi}{2}$. Than i plugged that into formula $\iint \sqrt{1+p^2+q^2}\,dx\,dy$ where $p=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ and $q=\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ and got $\frac{\sqrt{2}\pi}{2}$ but correct answer is $2\sqrt{2}\pi$. I probably need to multiply area with $4$ but honestly I'm not sure when to do that, on what it depends etc. I sketched this in plane(paraboloid and cylinder) and I can only see two symmetric areas (instead of four). If someone could clear this for me i would be very thankful.

Comment: You can see the Example 1 of the following link (https://home.iitk.ac.in/~psraj/mth101/lecture_notes/lecture35.pdf). This are more or less same.

Comment: First of all, $z^2 = x^2 + y^2$ is a cone and not a paraboloid. Second, your working is correct but only considers first octant. You need to multiply by $4$ and not $2$. It is $- \pi/2 \leq \phi \leq \pi/2$ but your working has $0 \leq \phi \leq \pi/2$. So you need to multiply your answer by $2$. That takes care of the cone $z = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$. But you have another cone below $XY$ plane (negative $z$), $z = - \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$. So you need to multiply by  $2$ again for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a basic algebra exercise to see that the horizontal cross-section of your cyclinder is a circle centered at $(1,0,0)$ on the $xy$-plane.

## $$\Huge{\lvert \hspace{-15px} \bigodot}$$

| object | `code` | $\text{equation}$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $\lvert$ | `$\lvert$` | $x = 0$ |
| $\bigodot$ | `$\bigodot$` | $(x-1)^2 + y^2 = 1$ |

It's clear that in your cylindrical coordinates $\begin{cases}x = r\cos \phi& \\ y = r\sin \phi,& \end{cases}$, $\phi$ represents the angle between the segment from $(0,0)$ to $(x,y)$ and the $x$-axis.  By setting $0\le \phi \le \dfrac{\pi}{2}$, you've only swept the first quadrant.  However, by observing the symmetry along the $xz$-plane (i.e. $y = 0$), <del>it suffices</del> you have to multiply your calculated value by $2$ to get the <del>correct answer</del> area for one slice.

As @MathLover has pointed out, there's another slide due to the symmetry along the $xy$-plane, so you have $$\frac{\sqrt2 \pi}{2} \cdot 4 = 2\sqrt2 \pi,$$ which is your desired answer.

Comment: There is also a symmetry along $XY$ plane. $z^2 = x^2 + y^2$ depicts two cones, one above $XY$ plane and one below $XY$ plane. So the calculated value has to be multiplied by $4$ and not $2$.

Comment: @MathLover Sorry for error. Thanks for pointing it out.  I've corrected it.

Comment: You are welcome!